# Looking to reset events after completion using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a slideshow in which text fades onto a specific slide. For example `text1` appears on `slide1`, `text2` appears on `slide2` etc. The slide show is automated but can also be clicked through by the user.

What I am looking to do is reset the faded text so that every time the user clicks to a new slide or the slide automatically changes the previous slide text fade event resets in preparation for the slideshow to come round again.

So, the slide comes in, text fades in, slideshow automates or user clicks to next slide, previous slide events reset.

I have looked at a reset function after the completion of each event but nothing seems to be working.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var t;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
  clearTimeout(t);
  showSlides(slideIndex);
  console.log(slideIndex);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  if (n == undefined) {
    n = ++slideIndex
  }

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt1S1').fadeIn(3000);
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt2S1').delay(1500).fadeIn(2500);
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt1S2').fadeIn(3000);
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt2S2').delay(1500).fadeIn(2500);
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt1S3').fadeIn(3000);
  $(slides[slideIndex - 1]).find('#fadeTxt2S3').delay(1500).fadeIn(2500);
  t = setTimeout(showSlides, 7500)
};
```

```css
#fadeTxt1S1 {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 250px;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #9B51E0;
}

#fadeTxt1S2 {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #9B51E0;
}

#fadeTxt1S3 {
  display: none;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 310px;
  right: 110px;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: serif;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #9B51E0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideShowContainer">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/slide3b.jpg">
    <p id="fadeTxt1S1">text 1 for slide 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/test2.jpg">
    <p id="fadeTxt1S2">text 1 for slide 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src="HomePage/test3.jpg">
    <p id="fadeTxt1S3">text 1 for slide 3</p>
  </div>
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&rsaquo;</a>
```

Comment: Could you please edit your text? I mean, I try to make sense of the second paragraph, but verbs and nouns just seem to follow each other without a clear cut between phrases. I cannot make sense of it. Also, events don't reset. Animation effects may reset. Make clear whether you mean the animation needs to flip to its final state or to its initial state. "Reset" seems to suggest the latter, but I doubt it is what you really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you mean with "reset events", but I will assume you want to end any ongoing animations.

For that you can add this line in your `showSlides` function, before the lines where you initiate new animations:

```
$('[id^="fadeTxt"]').finish();
```

This will match all elements that have "fadeTxt" at the start of their `id` attribute value, and stop any animation that is being applied to it, bringing them to their planned final animation state.